# Constraint icons missing from iOS8 Storyboard in XCode 6.4 for app that was originally written under earlier versions of iOS

Tags: ios, ios8, xcode6, storyboard, constraints

I wrote an app for iOS4 or iOS5. I upgraded it to iOS6. Adding the new constraints were rather traumatic (I had to almost completely redo the Storyboard and I had to create a bunch of constraints since they didn't exist before), but I got through it. Now I'm upgrading to iOS8 using XCode 6.4. I have written other apps in iOS8 and the constraint icons are always on the bottom; there are 3 of them: Align, Pin, and Resolve Auto-Layout. However, in this older app, all of these icons are missing (also the W Any H Any in the middle is missing as well). One of the constraints is wrong, but I can't fix it because I don't have any constraint icons. How do I get them back?

Here is a new app that shows the constraint icons:

[image]

Here is the old app with the constraint icons missing:

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Select the storyboard (on the left) and the File inspector (on the right; not present in your screen shots, you'll have to show it deliberately). The File inspector has a Use Auto Layout checkbox. If the storyboard doesn't use auto layout, you won't see those constraint icons.

Comment: That solved the problem. Thanks! I marked the answer as useful, but I need more user points before it will actually show up).

Answer (score 4):

If the autolayout checkbox is not available, quiting Xcode and reopening worked for me.